# Unable to export sound and video into the same file

Tags: rendering, video, audio

...I can get one or the other, but not both. I've used the Video Editing component to composite, with a sound track, and it plays fine in Blender, but I cannot get an actual A/V output file, in AVI or MPEG.

Help Please?!

Thank You.